# android tree-view-list

Tags: android, listview, treeview, tree

I´ve tried to work with the tree-view-list example for android from /[google](http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/)

the description says that the isLibrary flag has to be unset to compile the project. Unfortunatley I don´t know how to do this. I can´t find any is Library flag.

Did anybody work with this project before and could give me some advices how to work with?

Thanks in advance
Asuka

Comment: See is the link for My project where N-level Tree list view can be achieved. https://github.com/Jaldips/Android-MultilevelTreeListView

Answer (score 2):

It is probably referring to the `Is Library` property under `Project Properties -> Android` in Eclipse.

This toggle obviously changes whether your Android project builds as a library or as an installable application program; if it's not a library project, it can't be referenced from another Android project as a library.

It might be best to keep the `tree-view-list` library as a library and write an Android application program that references it (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) for how to do so).

Comment: Christine, if ravuya's response answered your question, you need to mark it as the Accepted Answer.